# Regular Expression - Find and Replace to clean up HTML documents

Tags: regex, replace

I attempted to research and write this expression myself, but alas, I gave up. I could never get a hold of RegEx. :) Ultimately, I want to clean up a large batch of HTML files. I would need two sets of expressions:

1. I want to select code that starts with `<!DOCTYPE` and ends with
   `<div id="content">`
2. I also want to also select code that starts with `</div><!-- end
   content -->` and ends with `</html>`

How would you write out these expressions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You should not use regular expressions to parse HTML.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/116810

Comment: Cool, thanks Kimball, I wasn't sure what to search for, I will look into those posts

Comment: Why are you cleaning up HTML?  Are you trying to tidy it up? Are you trying to remove unsafe tags, or something?  There are tools out there to do that.  But you need to edit your question to explain *why* you are doing what you are doing, without the assumption of using RegExes.

Comment: @KimballRobinson I think the term you're looking for is "XY Problem".

Comment: @Kimball - ok, to be more specific. I am taking HTML pages for a client and I want to remove these lines of code so that we can easily paste the remaining "body" content back into a Content Management System. Hopefully that clears it up. If there are tools, can you name some for me? I am using Dreamweaver and Visual Studio at the moment. But I also have Brackets and Atom installed as well. Perhaps there are plug-ins for those?

Comment: So, are you trying to use your text editor's regex (find/replace) tools to pull out the central content?  If so, which editor(s) are you trying?  Or are you writing a program?  If so, what language(s)?

Comment: I was simply attempting to use the Find and Replace tools in VS or Dreamweaver, checking the Use RegEx option, but I guess I should not be doing that?

Comment: @edwardm  I suppose you can use Regex tools for this, if you have a small set of files.  If you know how to write a program, I would lean toward doing that.  However, I am not familiar with the VS and dreamweaver toolkits, so I am not sure what dialect of regular expressions they use.  I suggest you add those to the question tags, though.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Didn't know there were different dialects of regex :)

Comment: The IDE I use lets me highlight a matching block of code.  Looks like VS does this too: http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/08/19/how-to-select-a-block-of-code-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Without using VS, I would guess you can select a code block (eg matching braces or html tags) by

- finding the opening content tag, using a non-regex search for `<div id="content">`
- Using this shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + ]` http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/08/19/how-to-select-a-block-of-code-in-visual-studio/
- Cutting.
- Deleting everything that's left (do not cut, just use the del key)
- Pasting.